# I have a table fetching values from an SP. I'd like to know if a combination of data is reversely repeated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named #hierachy, for which there are three columns:
childId, parentId, and linkType

The data is as follows:

```
childID  parentID  linktype
30  31          53
31  42          56
31  415349      18
31  437327      18
31  438333      18
35  32          56
32  35          18
32  38          52
32  39          52
32  439395      51
34  40          51
```

I'd like to spot any reverse repetitions and return a "true" or "1" if there is a reverse repetition between the first two columns childID and parentID
For example, the sixth and seventh lines are reversely similar: One is 35 then 32 and the other is the reverse: 32 and 35.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from t t2
                          where t2.childID = t.parentID and t2.parentID = t.childID
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as is_reversed
from t;
```

If the data is being returned from a stored procedure, you need to either put this logic in the stored procedure or put the data into a table and run the logic using that table.